# Angular import custom lib from dist like it's installed

Tags: angular, build, angular-library

In an older project I have this structure:

```
├─ dist  
├─ e2e  
├─ node_modules  
├─ projects  
│   ├─ lib1  
│   ├─ lib2  
│   ├─ lib3  
├─ demo app  
└─ all configuration file (like angular.json, tsconfig.json ecc)
```

Assume that `lib3` is a main lib that inlcude all other lib. When I import something from `lib1` or `lib2` in `lib3` i use simply `import { x } from "lib1"` and if `lib1` is installed, `lib3` search the module in node_modules instead if `lib1` isn't installed `lib3` search the module in `dist` folder! So if i build `lib1` I can import it like it was installed.

Now I create a new project with the same structure but I don't know why, when `lib1` isn't installed `lib3` not serach it in `dist` folder so if I would to import lib without installing it i must use the "runtime" import going up with the path `import { x } from "../../lib1"`.

There is an option that let me to have in second project the same behavior of the first project?

Comment: You need to use a monorepo tool like NX or Lerna. These fix the path mapping issues you're experiencing

Answer (score 0):

You cannot import it directly, as lib1, lib2, and lib3 are completely different projects placed inside the same workspace. So to use anything from library 1, you need to build it first and then you need to add it inside lib3 like we import libraries.

Comment: Yes, but do I need only to build it or also to install it? Because the issue is just this. In my old workspace I can import lib 1 from dist (having only build it), in second workspace I have to install it to import it directly